# Show AttributeErrors for Enum prior to runtime in Pycharm

Tags: python, enums, pycharm

Is there any way to detect AttributeErrors prior to runtime in Pycharm for child classes of Enum?

I have a simple child class of Enum:

```py
class ContentEncoding(Enum):
    UTF_8 = "utf-8"
    BINARY = "binary"
```

If I try accessing some non-existant field, e.g.:

```py
class ContentEncoding(Enum):
    UTF_8 = "utf-8"
    BINARY = "binary"


bar = ContentEncoding.foo
```

Pycharm doesn't show the usual `"Unresolved attribute reference 'foo' for class ContentEncoding` like I'd expect. The entire reason for using Enums in my case was to limit the values ContentEncoding could take. If there is no lint checks on this it seems kind of pointless to use an Enum in the first place.

#### Edit:

Adding the intended use-case for this Enum child class in hopes alternative solutions exist:

The intended use of this `ContentEncoding` class is to define the only valid encodings for some other encoder method.

For example, lets say this encoder method is as follows:

```py
def encode(obj, encoding: str):
    return black_box_encoder(obj, encoding)
```

where the only valid encoding str are "utf-8" or "binary". All other str would result in a runtime error.

So assume this ContentEncoding class and encode method are in some package called `mypackage` and I have a user who imports this package and wants to encode something.

```py
import mypackage

obj = "foo"

bar = mypackage.encode(obj, mypackage.ContentEncoding.UTF_8.value)
```

Rather than making the user manually type "utf-8" and be prone to typos like "UTF-8", "Utf-8", etc. I wanted to have an enum (or some other object) than can be used to predefine the only valid values for the 2nd arg of encode.

I guess it would be better to type hint to ContentEncoding rather than str and do the value extraction within the encode method. e.g.

```py
def encode(obj, encoding: ContentEncoding):
    return black_box_encoder(obj, encoding.value)
```

```py
import mypackage

obj = "foo"

bar = mypackage.encode(obj, mypackage.ContentEncoding.UTF_8)
```

Regardless, I'm still not seeing a way to get a lint/error check for an appropriate encoding string prior to runtime. If an alternative solution exists, please link me to something I can read up on.

To be clear, I want someway of having Pycharm (or other lint checker) to warn the user they have used an incorrect arg (prior to runtime) if they did something like this:

```py
import mypackage

obj = "foo"

bar = mypackage.encode(obj, mypackage.ContentEncoding.utf_8)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that PyCharm didn't warn you is because you inherit from `enum.Enum` which implements the methods `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`, and classes which have this method implemented means that attribute accessing is done manually, therefore PyCharm can't warn you for that.

```py
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return 1

class B(A):
    pass


bar = B().foo
print(bar)
```

results in "1" and PyCharm could not warn me since this work was done dynamically in `__getattr__`.

Comment: Ok so why PyCharm can't warn me makes sense, but why python's enum class is like this does not. Are you aware of any documentation as to why this is like this? This seems to make working with python enums very susceptible to unexpected runtime errors. Also do you have any comment on a better approach to limiting a class field to one of many predefined values? By better I mean not having to depend on runtime errors to debug my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "but why python's enum class is like this"? why doesn't it just keep them as regular class members? ok the answer is because every time you access an attribute it gives you the entire enum + the desired value, for example given Enum with A, B. enum.A will give you an instance of enum + the value A: enum.A.A.A.B.A.A will still be valid since everything is the enum object itself. in order to get the real value in the enum attribute and not the instance of the current enum you can do enum.A.value or enum.A.name to get its name ("A").
That's why attribute accessing is dynamic.

Comment: The `enum.A.A.A.B.A.A` will be going away.

Comment: @Jonathan1609 I added a section to the question to clarify my intended use case. If you are aware of an alternative solution I'd be eager to hear about it. If you think this is too tangential and warrants a new question, I can remove the edits and post elsewhere.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how enum.A will give you an instance of enum + value of A since if I add a field to your example `class B(A): FOO = "FOO"` and then print(type(B().FOO))` I get `<class 'str'>` not an enum type. Is there a better way than `type()` to show what you are referring to?

Comment: What is A? is it a class which inherits Enum?